# Reducing function calls with Map

Tags: python, hash-map

Currently I am working on reducing function calls in my tool.

My function is called  **add_field_and_calc**

```
    def add_field_and_calc(
        f_class, name_of_new_field, 
        condition, field):

    """Creates new field, make selection and fills with specific value from selection"""

    arcpy.AddField_management(f_class, name_of_new_field, "TEXT", field_length = 100)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(f_class, temp)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(temp, "NEW_SELECTION", condition)
    try:
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(temp, [field, name_of_new_field]) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                row[1] = row[0]
                cursor.updateRow(row)
    except RuntimeError:
        print(row[1])
    del row,cursor
```

I need to call it 20-30 times. Everytime with diffrent arguments.

I dont want to my code like this:

```
add_field_and_calc(
    fc_1,'Z6_Z8_city',condition_city,'osm_name')
add_field_and_calc(
    fc_1,'Z9_Z14_cityTown',condition_city_town,'osm_name')
add_field_and_calc(
    fc_1,'Z12_Z16_VillageSuburbQuarter',condition_village_suburb_quarter,'osm_name')
add_field_and_calc(
    fc_1,'Z15_20_5_smaller',condition_5_smaller,'osm_name')
add_field_and_calc(
    fc_1,'Z17_Z20_Square',condition_square,'osm_name')
```

Here is my try of maping function calls:

```
tupel_fc = [(
    fc_1, 'Z6_Z8_city',
    condition_city,'osm_name'),
    (fc_1, 'Z9_Z14_cityTown',
    condition_city_town,'osm_name'),
    (fc_1, 'Z12_Z16_VillageSuburbQuarter',
    condition_village_suburb_quarter,'osm_name'),
    (fc_1,'Z15_20_5_smaller',
    condition_5_smaller,'osm_name'),
    (fc_1,'Z17_Z20_Square',
    condition_square,'osm_name'),
    (...)] # <<< more records to come if this a good approach

#lambda to use all things from tupel
creating_lambda = lambda tupel: add_field_and_calc(
    tupel[0], tupel[1], tupel[2], tupel[3])

#map to eliminate need of copy - pasting same function many times
map(creating_lambda, tupel_fc)
```

Comment: Since syntax errors are raised by the parser before your code runs, if you have any your code can't possibly work. Could you ensure the code you've posted has none. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed it to look more clean.

Comment: The previous version should be fine, just your disclaimer says that you know the code doesn't work, and so it would be off-topic here.

Comment: It works fine now. I just need help with this part.

Comment: Please, don't edit your original code, It's against rules of Code Review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: You could fix the question by actually providing more code that would explain where all the `argX` variables are comming from. Currently it looks very hypothetical but maybe there is a reason for them. But as @Calak said, I'm not sure whether it wouldn't invalidate the answer. If your code really contains this snippet then it'd be ok to add a larger one; otherwise I'm afraid it's not loger fixable.

Comment: @Calak Please read that page again, it says you're not allowed to edit it _once you get answers_.

Comment: Edited post, it looked something like this but i missunderstood Peilonrayz reply. Original code is mostly arcpy - GIS stuff. It is not relevant to this matter. I wanted to give you overlook for my whole piece of a code. I made note about syntax error, becasue on other forum I posted once with some irrelevant syntax errors and got smashed for that. I am reworking my code from jupyter notebook to python-toolbox. So this code is hypothetical, beacause I just wanted some advice on maping function calls. I got one below from Graipher. Sorry for the trouble. I am kinda new to whole StackExchang

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your current code could be made nicer by using [tuple unpacking](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/). So instead of explicitly writing:

```
lambda tupel: add_field_and_calc(tupel[0], tupel[1], tupel[2], tupel[3])
```

you could just do:

```
lambda t: add_field_and_calc(*t)
```

---

But you could make it even simpler by using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap), which does this part for you:

```
from itertools import starmap

list(starmap(add_field_and_calc, tupel_fc))
```

Without the `list` call this is just a generator, which could be fine if you only ever iterate over it once.

Comment: So give me a hint how to fix this and it will be better.

Comment: @JuniorPythonNewbie: Add your actual `add_field_and_calc`, and/or add your actual parameters, so it looks less like a generic question but like your actual code.